# how to pass id as a parameter of FileUpload to javascript function to check extension and size of file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I am working on asp.net web application in which i have 6 FileUpload Controls 
for one file upload i have created a javascript method to check file extension and file size.
but how to pass id of FileUpload upload dynamically so that only in only one method i can validate all FileUpload 
my code of javacript is

```
  var validFilesTypes = ["bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "doc", "docx",         "xls", "xlsx", "htm", "html", "rar", "zip", "txt", "pdf"];
    function CheckExtension() {
        /*global document: false */
        var file = document.getElementById("<%=txtTenderDoc.ClientID%>");
        var path = file.value;
        var ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, path.length).toLowerCase();
        var isValidFile = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < validFilesTypes.length; i++) {
            if (ext == validFilesTypes[i]) {
                isValidFile = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isValidFile) {
            alert("Invalid File. Unknown Extension Of Tender Doc" + "Valid extensions are:\n\n" + validFilesTypes.join(", "));
        }
        return isValidFile;
    }

    function validateFileSize() {
        /*global document: false */
        var file = document.getElementById("<%=txtTenderDoc.ClientID%>");
        var fileSize = file.files[0].size;
        var isValidFile = false;
        if (fileSize !== 0 && fileSize <= 25214400) {
            isValidFile = true;
        }
        if (!isValidFile) {
            alert("File Size Should be Greater than 0 and less than 25 mb");
        }
        return isValidFile;
    }
```

and i have used this in aspx page

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="txtTenderDoc" onchange="var result= CheckExtension();validateFileSize(); return result"
                        runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
```

as you can see i have to create **6 method** by this to check file size and file extension how to do that in only one method....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching on net finally i have solved the issue and posting it so that if anyone had similar problem this should help

```
 // set which files are allowed in FileUpload Control
    var validFilesTypes = ["bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "htm", "html", "rar", "zip", "txt", "pdf"];
    function CheckExtension(file) {
        /*global document: false */
        var path = file.value;
        var ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, path.length).toLowerCase();
        var isValidFile = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < validFilesTypes.length; i++) {
            if (ext == validFilesTypes[i]) {
                isValidFile = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isValidFile) {
            alert("Invalid File. Unknown Extension Of Tender Doc" + "Valid extensions are:\n\n" + validFilesTypes.join(", "));
        }
        return isValidFile;
    }

    function validateFileSize(file) {
        /*global document: false */
        //getting size of the file
        var fileSize = file.files[0].size;
        var isValidFile = false;
        if (fileSize !== 0 && fileSize <= 25214400) {
            isValidFile = true;
        }
        if (!isValidFile) {
            alert("File Size Should be Greater than 0 and less than 25 mb");
        }
        return isValidFile;
    }
```

and calling these method in FileUpload Control like that

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuTenderDoc" onchange="var result=CheckExtension(this);validateFileSize(this); return result"
                        runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>

<asp:FileUpload ID="fuBidDoc" onchange="var result=CheckExtension(this);validateFileSize(this); return result"
                        runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>

 <asp:FileUpload ID="fuTechnicalDoc" onchange="var result=CheckExtension(this);validateFileSize(this); return result"
                        runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function CheckExtension(Id) {
    /*global document: false */
    var file = document.getElementById(Id);
    var path = file.value;
    var ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, path.length).toLowerCase();
    var isValidFile = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < validFilesTypes.length; i++) {
        if (ext == validFilesTypes[i]) {
            isValidFile = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isValidFile) {
        alert("Invalid File. Unknown Extension Of Tender Doc" + "Valid extensions are:\n\n" + validFilesTypes.join(", "));
    }
    return isValidFile;
}   


function validateFileSize(Id) {
    /*global document: false */
    var file = document.getElementById(Id);
    var fileSize = file.files[0].size;
    var isValidFile = false;
    if (fileSize !== 0 && fileSize <= 25214400) {
        isValidFile = true;
    }
    if (!isValidFile) {
        alert("File Size Should be Greater than 0 and less than 25 mb");
    }
    return isValidFile;
}

<asp:FileUpload ID="txtTenderDoc" onchange="var result=      CheckExtension('textTenderDoc');validateFileSize('textTenderDoc'); return result"  runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
```

I'm assuming that your creating six different file upload controls. This way you can pass the id into the java script at compile time so you have only one method.

Comment: i have tried this and in firebug i got error
Uncaught Typeerror: cannot read property 'value' of null
 near this line var path = file.value;

Comment: You need to check the value being passed in for Id and see if that matches the input being drawn in the page. Probably should check if file is null too.